# Use of unresolved identifier 'Info' and Invalid redecoration of 'signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp' error

Tags: swift, xcode6.3

I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'Info'` when I enter this code:

```
func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController) {
    if let password = info?["password"] as? String {
        return password.utf16count >= 8
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

---

Also, I get `Invalid redecoration of 'signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp'` when I enter this code:

```
func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController) {
    println("User dismissed sign up")
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Please excuse my lack of knowledge, I am still learning code.

Comment: Where did you declare the variable info? and how are you calling signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp?

Comment: is Info a class level variable. The function signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp does not include info as parameter. 

You cannot can have the same function defined more than once in a class, hence you get invalid redeclaration error.

Comment: Can you add that to your question? It seems that info is out of scope and that signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp is been called with the wrong parameters

Comment: @IcaroNZ How would I declare Info?